# How to get file from S3 for bootstrapping application using CloudFormation template and without launching EC2 instances with a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I need to download a file from S3 bucket which is a private location. I have created an IAM Role using AWS Console - hence an have an IAM Profile which I assign to instances launched. I can get the file from secure location by providing an Authentication Object in LaunchConfiguration. This only works if the instance is launched with an `IamInstanceProfile`.

```
   "LaunchConfiguration":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "Metadata":{
            "Comment":"Configure the Presentation Tier",
             "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                "S3Access" : {
                    "type" : "S3",
                    "buckets":["demo-upload"],
                    "roleName": "MYS3ROLE"
                }
            },
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":{
                "config":{
                    "packages":{
                        "yum":{
                            "tomcat6": [],
                            "java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel" : [],
                            "tomcat6-webapps" :[],
                            "tomcat6-admin-webapps" :[],
                            "tomcat6-docs-webapp" :[],
                            "curl":[]
                        }
                    },
                    "files":{
                        "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo.war" : { 
                            "source" : {"Ref":"WarLoc"},
                            "owner" : "tomcat",
                            "group" : "tomcat",
                            "authentication":"S3Access"
                        },
                        "/root/demo.war" : { 
                            "source" : {"Ref":"WarLoc"},
                            "owner" : "root",
                            "group" : "root",
                            "authentication":"S3Access"
                        },
                        "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf" : {
                            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                            "[main]\n",
                            "stack=", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
                            "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                            "interval=1"
                            ]]},
                        "mode"    : "000400",
                        "owner"   : "root",
                        "group"   : "root"
                        },

                      "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
                        "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                          "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                          "triggers=post.update\n",
                          "path=Resources.LaunchConfiguration.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                          "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" },
                          "         -r LaunchConfiguration ",
                          "         --region     ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                          "runas=root\n"
                        ]]}
                      }
                    },
                    "services" : {
                        "sysvinit" : {
                            "tomcat6":{
                                "files":["/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo.war"],
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "ensureRunning":"true"
                            },
                            "cfn-hup":{
                                "files":["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf","/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"],
                                "enabled":"true",
                                "ensureRunning":"true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Properties":{
            "ImageId"        : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
            "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
            "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
            "InstanceMonitoring": "false",
            "KeyName"        : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "true",
            "IamInstanceProfile":"arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:instance-profile/MYS3ROLE",
            "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
              "yum update -y\n",
              "# Install Presentation Software\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r LaunchConfiguration ",
              "    --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
              "service tomcat6 stop\n",
              "rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo\n",
              "sleep 3\n",
              "service tomcat6 start\n",
              "sleep 3\n",
              "service tomcat6 restart\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? -r \"Setup complete\" '", { "Ref" : "WaitHandle" }, "'\n"
              ]]}}
        }
    },
```

Can I download the files from S3 which is not public without having to launch the machine with an `IamInstanceProfile`. ?

If I delete the the `"IamInstanceProfile":"arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:instance-profile/s3access",` then in `/var/log/cfn-init.log` I find the following lines, which I don't think would be because of Authentication Faiures

```
ToolError: Failed to retrieve https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/demo-upload/0.0.1/demo.war: [Errno 404] HTTP Error 404 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>404 - Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I launch the Instance with IamProfile everything runs fine. So, is there a way to get the files - without scripts and storing credentials on machine - but not have instance launched with a role ?

Comment: Curious, what's the reason for not using the IAM Role in the Instance Profile?  They are great, in that they provide the instance with temporary credentials that can only be accessed by the instance.

Comment: Yes, that's great and convenient, but was just looking if it is possible without IamProfile OR Access-Secret keys stored on instance. Also, since I cannot control expiration time of Access and Secret key's generated by InstanceMetaDataService (IMDS) which is valid for 6 hours. Once generated (and someone gets it) the same can be used anywhere - not just EC2 Instance, so was just "searching" if it is possible to do without it.

Comment: Hey thanks, I got it in my head somewhere that the temporary token couldn't be used outside the instance.  Must have confused using the token with assuming the role (restricted by trust relationship).

Answer (score 1):

IAM Instance profile is the cleanest way to get a private file from S3 to EC2.

Other options are (apart from keeping key in code - which is not good!):

- Instance Metadata and User Data - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html
- Use a deployment service like [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) or [OpsWorks](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/). You can pass anything to the EC2s started this way. In fact this is an easy way to manage clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to access S3 from an EC2 instance without credentials, but I do have an idea for you.

1. You can create your IAM Role inside your template, but without a policy (or an empty policy if semantics make you specify one).
2. Create an instance with this Role (You may need to make a WaitCondition).
3. After the instance has been created (you will need a WaitCondition), create an IAM Role Policy that has the permissions you need and which restricts access to the Instance's IP address. Have it attach to the Role you created.

Your instance should have access to the resources it needs before it fully boots.

Comment: Restricting access to Instance IP Address sounds good for single instance. But how would I do that in for EC2 instances in an AutoScaling group ?

Comment: You could try restricting by the auto-scaling group's ARN.  But, if you're in an auto scaling group, aren't your instances behind a firewall and a load balancer?  What about your setup makes it easy for an attacker to get your credentials, but hard for an attacker to make requests from the machine itself?

Comment: Yes, it is behind a load balancer and combined with security groups and firewall it makes it harder for an attacker to get inside. I could try restricting by AutoScaling group's ARN - studying on that, but I guess for that I would need to create the InstanceProfile and it's policy in cloudformation template. Currently I first create the Role using IAM Console and then use them in templates. Thanks.